# Android dynamic shortcuts not opening proper activity second time

Tags: android, android-activity, shortcut, android-static-shortcuts, android-dynamic-shortcuts

Hi I am developing shortcuts for android application. My code looks like

```
private void setShortMenu() {

    ArrayList<ShortcutInfo> shortcutInfos = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleActivity2.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.putExtra("val",1);
    intent.addCategory("android.shortcut.conversation");
    ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

    ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "id2")
            .setShortLabel("Web site")
            .setLongLabel("Open the web site")
            .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setIntent(intent)
            .build();
    shortcutInfos.add(shortcut);

    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, SampleActivity3.class);
    intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory("android.shortcut.conversation");
    intent.putExtra("val",2);

    ShortcutInfo shortcut2 = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "id1")
            .setShortLabel("Web site...")
            .setLongLabel("Open the web site...")
            .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setIntent(intent2)
            .build();
    shortcutInfos.add(shortcut2);

    shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(shortcutInfos);
}
```

My manifest looks like this :

```
<application
    android:name=".SampleApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            <!--<meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />-->
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SampleActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SampleActivity2" />
    <activity android:name=".SampleActivity3"></activity>
```

Issue with this code is like this. I killed application from background. click on first shortcut. It opens `SampleActivity2`. I minimised the application by clicking home button and click on second shortcut. It opens `SampleActivity3`. Till this point everything is correct. But now if I click on first menu or second menu it always opens `SampleActivity3` which is last minimised activity.
If I do same thing thing with static way of shortcuts then it works fine:

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="compose"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.nilkash.shortcutmenu"
        android:targetClass="com.example.nilkash.shortcutmenu.SampleActivity2" >
        <extra android:name="val" android:value="1" />
    </intent>
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
</shortcut>

<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="compose1"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label2"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label2"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label2">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.nilkash.shortcutmenu"
        android:targetClass="com.example.nilkash.shortcutmenu.SampleActivity3" >
        <extra android:name="val" android:value="2" />
    </intent>
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
</shortcut>
```

and in manifest I added :

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
            android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
    </activity>
```

Is there any thing wrong in my code. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: post your manifest.

Comment: Updated question with manifest code. Please help me you out.

Comment: See my answer for a description of what is happening. What would you like to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be confirmed after you post your manifest, but I'm guessing the following is happening:

When you use the first shortcut, Android creates a new task for your app and launches `SampleActivity2` into the task. You then press HOME, which just sends this task to the background.

Now you use the second shortcut. Because `SampleActivity3` has the same `taskAffinity` as `SampleActivity2`, Android brings the existing task containing `SampleActivity2` to the foreground and launches `SampleActivity3` into that task. Your task now contains `SampleActivity2`->`SampleActivity3`. You now press HOME again. The task is moved to the background.

If you now use the first shortcut, Android recognizes that you are trying to launch the "root" `Activity` of an existing task, and just brings the existing task to the foreground and does not launch any new `Activity` into it. The task contains `SampleActivity2`->`SampleActivity3` so you will see `SampleActivity3` since this is the top `Activity` in the task. This behaviour is exactly the same as when you have, for example, Whatsapp running, press HOME, then press the Whatsapp icon on your HOME screen. This doesn't "start Whatsapp from the beginning", it just brings the current task containing Whatsapp to the foreground in whatever state it was in when it was moved to the background.

If you now press HOME and use the second shortcut, Android finds your task with the same `taskAffinity` as `SampleActivity3` and brings the existing task to the foreground. Android will now either do nothing (if `SampleActivity3` has `launchMode="singleTop"`) or create a new instance of `SampleActivity3` and launch that into the task. In that case your task will contain 3 `Activity` instances: `SampleActivity2`->`SampleActivity3`->`SampleActivity3` and you will see `SampleActivity3` since this is the top `Activity` in the task.

---

**NOTE:** As can be seen in the comment discussion below, it is important to add

```
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

to the `Intent` used to launch the `Activity` if you want to ensure that a new instance of the `Activity` is created. Otherwise, Android will just bring the existing task to the foreground and won't launch any new `Activity`.

Comment: On more observation I found regarding same thing. If I implement it with static way of shortcuts with same type of intents. Then it works fine. But if I do it with dynamic way of shortcuts it doesn't work fine. Is there any difference between these two approaches. If no then it should behave in similar manner in both cases. Please correct me if any thing wrong. I updating my  question with static way as well. Please help me out.

Comment: Please explain what "it works fine" means. What do you expect to happen if your app is in the background started from shortcut 1 and you click on shortcut 2? Have you tested what happens when your app is running and you use a static shortcut and press the BACK button? There are about a dozen different ways to construct this and it depends on the navigation that you want (or think you want) in each case. You can view the activity stack at any time by using `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`

Comment: So scenario is like this in case of static shortcut --> clicked on shortcut1 it opens SampleActivity1. Click home button and bring app to background. Now click shortcut2 it opens SampleActivity2.Click home button and bring app to background. Now again click on shortcut1 ->  it opens SampleActivity1 which is fine.

Comment: Now scenario 2 is like this in case of dynamic shortcut : --> clicked on shortcut1 it opens SampleActivity1. Click home button and bring app to background. Now click shortcut2 it opens SampleActivity2.Click home button and bring app to background. Now again click on shortcut1 ->  it opens SampleActivity2 which is not correct. It should open SampleActivity1

Comment: OK. You need to look at what is happening in the static shortcut scenarios. After you click on the shortcut, execute the "adb" command and see what activities are in the stack for your task. You also need to see what happens if you press the BACK button after you click the shortcuts. Is `SampleActivity1` underneath `SampleActivity2` after you click the second shortcut? Or does Android completely clear the task and finish all activities in it before launching the shortcut `Activity`?

Comment: Ok sure will do that and get back with some more information.

Comment: I did investigation into it and checked activity stack: So observation is like this. In case of dynamic stack will like this : ` Activities=[ActivityRecord{4f95ab1 u0 com.example.nilkash.shortcutmenu/.SampleActivity3 t153}, ActivityRecord{866975c u0 com.example.nilkash.shortcutmenu/.SampleActivity2 t153}]`  But incase of static : `      Activities=[ActivityRecord{e59e7c6 u0 com.example.nilkash.shortcutmenu/.SampleActivity3 t157}]`. So definitely there is a difference between these two approaches.

Comment: So Android is clearing the task stack before starting the shortcut. You can simulate that yourself by calling `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)` to your shortcut `Intent`s that you use for dynamic shortcuts. Please try that.

Comment: Yes using these two flags I am able to achieve my result. thank you for help.

Comment: No problem. Glad you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser make you comment as the answer. It worked for me as well.